# NodeJS no muestra los errores

Tags: javascript, nodejs, backend

Estoy utilizando nodeJS y la librería nodemon en un proyecto.
Hace pocos días cuando tenia algún error, se mostraban en la consola de esta forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto era bastante útil porque me especificaba que estaba fallando y en donde.
Desde ayer me muestra los errores solo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me da ninguna información, y es mas complicado encontrar los errores.
Saben si es alguna actualización de una librería o que sucedió?

Comment: Inicia, y haces algo para que te muestre ese error?

Comment: Si, para el ejemplo llame mal a una función aproposito para que me mostrará el error. Pero solo me muestra el mensaje de app crashed en vez de mostrar dónde falla como antes

Comment: Es decir, no quiero resolver el error. Quiero que el node muestre el error en la consola como hacía antes

Comment: Usas express? Posiblemente no estas capturando tus errores en un `catch`. Puedes poner mas código?

Comment: En vez de ejecutar `nodemon` tal como lo haces actualmente, intenta levantar el servidor directamente con `node src/index.js`, para que puedas ver la traza de error y lo soluciones. Por otro lado, para `logging`, siempre es preferible utilizar alguna librería. `morgan` es muy famosa. Te sugiero que leas [ask] y [mcve]. Es [preferible el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-código-vale-más-que-mil-imágenes-cómo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu/3976#3976) que las imágenes. Saludos

Comment: Si inicio el servidor con node src/index.js, al ocurrir cualquier error solo cierra el proceso sin decir nada. No coloque codigo porque no quiero solucionar un error de codigo, solo quiero saber porque node ya no muestra los errores en consola como antes, ya que eso era bastante util